# How to use JMX in Python?

Tags: python, connect, jmx

I program with python, and I want to monitor a Java application, by communicating with JMX.

I searched the web and did not find a proven solution.
I find jmx4python, jmxquery and JPype but I did not know how to use them.

Does anyone have a suggestion of a framework or a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do that using the jmxquery 0.6.0

here it is the URL or you can just go to the pypi.org and look for it

[https://pypi.org/project/jmxquery/#:~:text=JMXQuery%20Python%20Module%20Provides%20a%20Python%20module%20to,of%20the%20values%20it%20finds%20matching%20the%20query](https://pypi.org/project/jmxquery/#:%7E:text=JMXQuery%20Python%20Module%20Provides%20a%20Python%20module%20to,of%20the%20values%20it%20finds%20matching%20the%20query).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32340106)